# What is the right permission set to run json input steps for another users?

Tags: jenkins, permissions, pentaho-data-integration

User A:

- Creates a Pentaho 9.3 install
- Creates a folder with all repository folders
- Creates a custom .kettle folder
- Set the kettle folder for the process
- Run a job (no errors)

User B (Jenkins agent):

- Set the kettle folder for the process
- Run the job (Errors happens on pentaho job)

There is 2 steps where this error should be happen:

- Rest Client step
- JSON input step

I solve the problem giving full controll to the user B (jenkins) on all Pentaho insttalation folder and files.

But to prevent security problems, I desire to know what is the right set of permissions to do the same thing.

Someone know the right way to do that?
P/S: JRE inside pentaho folder